# use RS-485 or Normal Voltage as Input over 10 meters

Tags: spi, rs485

Newbie when it comes to data transmission, no test equipment or any so i can't verify it actual, much of a idea so i would to ask those who have practical expertise. I have this setup where i came up on a long distance SPI using rs-485. Distance is about 10 - 20 meters. Now what bugs me will be the CS/SS.

This is a dumb Question of me (i guess) so sorry if i had to ask. should i use rs-485 transmitter and receiver for my CS/SS (image below)

**EDIT:** SPI here is a slave sensor that is being read by uC upon selection.

**EDIT:** i used this solution for applying long distance SPI to RS-485 http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt441/slyt441.pdf

[image]

or just use plain voltage input switched by a transistor/mosfet and uC (image below should i add bypass cap at the end near cs)

[image]

Is there a concern of transmission response, propagation, noise, etc?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using master to dumb-slave single-direction long distance SPI then using RS485 buffers for data and clock is fine so, instead of transmitting chip select, why don't you gate the clock signal sent (prior to 485 conversion) instead of sending a seperate CS line? Then at the slave end you have CS active all the time.

Be aware that if you are thinking of using SPI to talk to and get responses from an intelligent slave, you might have bitten-off more than you can chew unless your clock rate is quite slow.

Comment: I suppose the slave might have a low power mode when /CS is high, in which case a separate signal could make sense. But only if the power saved is significantly higher than the power needed to drive a RS485 transceiver + termination. Which in turn probably isn't likely.

Comment: It is an intelligent slave, i mean the SPI slave device is a sensor that it it would send data back to uC upon selected & read.

Comment: @Mheruian Then you can perhaps gate the CS with the clock. However, you'll need both MOSI and MISO. So what you are looking for here is rather RS-422 full duplex: same transceivers but one per signal.

Comment: @Mheruian what data rates are you expecting to use? Bearing in mind that at the point the slave responds, its response is "late" due to the cable delay and, there is one more cable delay in getting back to the master hence data returned is out of sync with the master clock by two cable lengths in effect. I calcuate that a 1 MHz clock is about the best you can realistically achieve for 20 metres cable.

Comment: @Lundin ok, i'll try looking that one :D thanks. Also i want to ask something, clock you mean the SPI master's serial clock?

Comment: @Andyaka :D ahh, well i guess i forgot i followed this one http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt441/slyt441.pdf, going to edit to include it in my question

Comment: @Mheruian Yes, in SPI you must provide a clock to the slaves. Which turns problematic here, as Andy points out. If you have a transmission delay, the master might end up clocking in MISO bits wrong, you get so-called "clock skew".